# How can i set google maps object into mobx observable

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, mobx, mobx-react

I wanted to use it by assigning it to a mobx observable, but the method does not perform a deep copy.

I wonder how to use it.

this is that code.

```
// mobx: store.js
@action
    setMapObject(obj: any): void {
        this.mapObject = obj;
    }
```

```
//react
...

 let map = new window.google.maps.Map(
                document.getElementById('gmap') as HTMLElement,
                {
                    center,
                    zoom
                }
            );

            this.props.mapStore.setMapObject(
                window.google.maps
            );

...
```

This is the approximate result of the code above.

```
// store.mapObject

this.mapObject = {
  Animation: ...,
  BicyclingLayer: ...,
  CameraParams: ...,
  Circle: res(), // google maps method is not deep copy
  ...
}
```

I hope you can help me with my problems..

Comment: Why would you want a deep copy? What is the end goal?

Comment: I will use other map APIs, but I want to manage them as modules, so I want to reassign them to the global variables of the mobx store.